# C Help - output to spell input by letters

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out the best way to have C spell out a given word. I already have it spelling the given word in reverse.

Input: test

Output:

t

e

s

t

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char [], int, int);
int main()
{
char str1[12];
int size, counter;

printf("Enter a string to reverse: ");
scanf("%s", str1);
printf("string1 with each character on a new line:")


printf("string1 printed backwards: \n");
size = strlen(str1);
reverse(str1, 0, size - 1);
printf("The string after reversing is: %s\n", str1);
return 0;
}

void reverse(char str1[], int index, int size) 
{ // Reversing the string using recursion
char temp;
temp = str1[index];
str1[index] = str1[size - index];
str1[size - index] = temp;
if (index == size / 2) 
{
    return;
}
reverse(str1, index + 1, size);
}
```

Comment: Can you share any code with us?

Comment: added the code.

Comment: I guess the next step is to use a loop / counter as subscript maybe, but I'm pretty stuck. Reading through "C Programming" by Wikibooks.

Comment: The code for reversing the string seems irrelevant here; it'd be better if you show the code that attempts to "spell" the word. From your output, you probably want to loop through the individual characters and print each of them with a newline.

Comment: Sorry, it is just part of my current code. Well the only way I can think of would be using getchar() and putchar() but that is for an integer.

Comment: Although the argument to `putchar()` is an integer (`int`), the value is converted to `unsigned char` by `putchar()` and then printed.  So you can pass an `unsigned char` or a `signed char` or a plain `char` and it will work sanely too.  This mainly means '`putchar()` isn't a problem'.

Comment: What would be the best way in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("Enter a string to reverse: ");
scanf("%s", str1);
size = strlen(str1);
printf("string1 with each character on a new line:\n");
int i;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%c\n", str1[i]);

printf("string1 printed backwards: \n");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain to me how does it spell out each letter?

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%c\n", str1[i]);

Comment: for printf function '\' is escape character. \n means "new line" and printf prints a new line for each iteration. Please check for detailed information: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant how does it know which letter to print out. Not the new line function ☺

Comment: str1 is a char array. In C arrays you can access elements by saying str[0] str[1] etc. just said for i(0 to size-1) access str[i]